# Disable memoization (@Memoized annotation) in tests

Tags: groovy

I have a method having @Memoized annotation.

It works perfectly but I want to disable memoization in the unit tests to have empty cache for each test.

Is there a way?

UPD: solution1:

```
boolean isProduction = true

@Memoized
def methodWithMemoize(String param){
    println("methodWithMemoize param [$param]")
}

def methodWithNoMemoize(String param){
    println("methodWithNoMemoize param [$param]")
}

def method = isProduction ? "methodWithMemoize" : "methodWithNoMemoize"

"$method"("hello")
```

Comment: wrap the annotation-free method into annotated one

Comment: @injecteer Could, do you mean doing like this?

```
boolean isProduction = true

def methodWithMemoize(String param){
    println("methodWithMemoize param [$param]")
}

def methodWithNoMemoize(String param){
    println("methodWithNoMemoize param [$param]")
}

def method = isProduction ? "methodWithMemoize" : "methodWithNoMemoize"

"$method"("hello")
```

Comment: what test framework are you using?

Comment: I am using Spock Framework.

Comment: I think Spock pefroms each test run from clean sheat, so you don't have to worry about emptying cache at all

Comment: also, the "solution" you shown is rather bad idea, as your code would behave totally different in prod and in unit-test. So, the whole idea of testing is hereby defeated

Comment: For investigation proposes I copied my test to the new one with different name. 2nd test failed because of the non-empty cache. So, looks like I should find the way to run tests in different 'test suites' some way.

Comment: so you instead of disabling the `@Memoized` you want rather to clean it's cache in your tests. I'm not aware about such a hook. You might want to show your test case to properly asses the possible options.

Comment: hmmm what you may try is to call `System.gc()` before (or after) each test run. See http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.4.9/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Memoized.html

Comment: If it's Memoized, surely the expectation is that it will return the same value each time?